# IF statement to check if loaded entity is of type

Tags: 7, entities

In my module (fork of ECK Clone) I'm trying to set a default value when an entity of type "Course" is cloned.

#### Currently I do:

```
function eck_clone_clone_entity($entity, $account = FALSE) {

  $original_entity = clone $entity;

  $entity->id = NULL;

  if ($account && isset($entity->uid)) {
    $entity->uid = $account->uid;
  }

  if (isset($entity->created)) {
    $entity->created = NULL;
  }

  if (isset($entity->changed)) {
    $entity->changed = NULL;
  }

  if (isset($entity->title)) {
    $entity->title = t('Clone of !title', array('!title' => $entity->title));
  }

  $entity->status = 1;
  $entity->some_boolean = 1;
  $entity->content_status = 1164;

  $context = array('original_entity' => $original_entity);

  drupal_alter('clone_eck', $entity, $context);

  entity_save($entity->type, $entity);

  return $entity;
}
```

*PS: some_boolean value gets set, but not the status. I wonder why.*

What I need is to check if the $entity is of the type "Course".
I thought it would be as simple as wrapping it in an if statement like so:

```
if($type == 'course') {
    $entity->some_boolean = 0;
    $entity->content_status = 665;
    $entity->course_number = 3;
    $entity->tag_line = "some other tag line here";
  }
```

But that doesn't work. Any idea?
PS: some_boolean value gets set, but not the status.

Comment: In your code above, $type is never set.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Kevin pointed out, $type was never set. That was helpful.
I believe this works:

```
if($entity->type == 'course') {
  $entity->some_boolean = 0;
  $entity->content_status = 665;
  $entity->course_number = 3;
  $entity->tag_line = "some other tag line here";
}
```

If you can improve this, please let me know. Much appreciated.